# Understanding case expression in the "Where" clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got this code here and you can see from my Pseudocode what I'm trying to accomplish

```
select *

from dbo.BenefitsForms
     inner join Dependents on BenefitsForms.UserId = Dependents.BenefitsForm_UserId
     inner join CoverageLevels on BenefitsForms.MedicalId = CoverageLevels.Id

where (BenefitsForms.MedicalId > 0 AND BenefitsForms.MedicalId < 13)
  AND Dependents.IsSpouse = CASE when CoverageLevels.[Level] = 2 then 1
                                 when CoverageLevels.[Level] = 3 then 0 end
                                 when CoverageLevels.[Level] = 4 then [any, it doesnt matter] <--- my desire but it doesn't work.
```

What can I do to get the effect I desire in the brackets? If Coverage Level = 4 then I don't care what Dependents.IsSpouse is, I don't even need to sort by it anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that `isSpouse` can only be `0` or `1`... if `CoverageLevels.Level` is `4`, then compare `isSpouse` to itself, which will always result in `true`:

```
AND Dependents.IsSpouse = CASE 
    when CoverageLevels.[Level] = 2 then 1
    when CoverageLevels.[Level] = 3 then 0
    when CoverageLevels.[Level] = 4 then Dependents.IsSpouse
END
```

Alternately, this can also be expressed without the `CASE`:

```
WHERE
    BenefitsForms.MedicalId > 0 
    AND BenefitsForms.MedicalId < 13
    AND (
        (Dependents.IsSpouse = 1 AND CoverageLevels.[Level] = 2)
        OR (Dependents.IsSpouse = 0 AND CoverageLevels.[Level] = 3)
        OR CoverageLevels.[Level] = 4
    )
```

Comment: Beat me by a full minute :(  Good solution